# VBA: Method or Data member not found. FindString for Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, variables, combobox

I get this error when I am trying to open a UserForm. What I want is to add to a combobox all the different objects (not repeated) that are present in a column.

I have been looking some solutions around there and all I can say until now is Yes, I have a combobox called "offer1"

When it gives me the error, it highlight the .FindString() method inside the loop

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim text As String

text = rCell.text
ws = Offers

offer1.Clear

With offer1
    For Each rCell In Sheets("Offers").Range("A2", Sheets("Offers").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If TEST.offer1.FindString(text) = -1 Then
            .AddItem CStr(text)
        End If
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

(If you see some silly mistakes with the names of variables as "Ofertas" or something like that is probably that I translated some variable names to english, and I jumped over a few)

Thanks a lot

Comment: well, what's `TEST` ?

Comment: and what is offer1? You have not set either of the objects.

Comment: TEST is the UserForm where the combobox 'offer1' is. Do I need to Dim the combobox also? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim strFirstCell As String

Set ws = Sheets("Offers")
With Me.offer1
    .Clear
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    strFirstCell = ws.Cells(2, "A").Address
    For Each rCell In ws.Range(strFirstCell, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((" & strFirstCell & ":" & rCell.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rCell.Address & ")+0)") = 1 And rCell.Value <> "" Then
            .AddItem rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

This will fill your combobox with all the unique items in column A, starting at row 2, while also skipping any blanks.

Comment: Hello TheEngineer, now I have the same problema and it highlights the first text '.Cells' inside 'strFirstCell'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi again, I just added 'ws' before '.Cells' and I don't get any error, but it just Add 1 ítem, not every ítem in the column. Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you step through your code, what value do you get for LastRow?